# Next & previous through @user's object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently if a person clicks the `link_to` they're brought to the previous or next challenge.

But how can `link_to` work where only `@user` `s challenges are included?

**view**

```
<% if @challenge.previous %>
  <%= link_to 'Prev', challenge_path(@challenge.previous), class: "footer-left", style: "color: white; font-style: normal;" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Home', root_url, class: "footer-left" %>
<% end %>

<% if @challenge.next %>
  <%= link_to 'Next', challenge_path(@challenge.next), class: "footer-right" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to 'Home', root_url, class: "footer-right" %>
<% end %>
```

**model**

```
def next
  Challenge.where("id > ?", id).first # I get nil error for... Challenge.find_by(user_id: @user.id).where("id > ?", id).first
end

def previous
  Challenge.where("id < ?", id).last # I get nil error for... Challenge.find_by(user_id: @user.id).where("id > ?", id).last
end
```

I know `@user` doesn't work in the model, but I'm just using it as an example for trying to get the `User` whose challenges they belong to.

Comment: Is there a `has_many` relationship between User and Challenge?

Comment: Does it ever work or only once you get to the last challenge

Comment: `@user.challenges.where('id > ?', @challenge.id).first` should return the challenge with the next higher id, assuming that a user has many challenges.

Comment: Unrelated, but I'd be pretty nervous with using a simple `<>` comparison to determine previous/next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To browse the user chalenges i'm assuming that your models look like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :challenges
end

class Challenge < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So your method should be:

```
class Challenge < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  #don't use just "next" because it's a ruby reserved keyword that you can use to skip to the next iteration of a loop
  def next_user_challenge
    user.challenges.where('id > ?', id).first
  end

  def previous_user_challenge
    user.challenges.where('id > ?', id).last
  end
end
```

And one more point, to browse the next and previous challenges i think that would be better if you compare the challenge's date or some other  attribute. Example:

```
#next challenge
user.challenges.where('challenge_date > ?', challenge_date).order('challenge_date ASC').first

#previous challenge
user.challenges.where('challenge_date < ?', challenge_date).order('challenge_date ASC').first
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you! I use two separate date categories for challenges: `deadline` and `date_started`. Do you know a way I could order via meshing both together?